# Python BeautifulSoup, how to store text in between tags and symbols

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

```
from urllib import request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs 
#Used these libs
```

I need to store both of these 'texts' how would I do that,

```
<option value="/random-file/76/6/">Thing</option>
<option value="/random-file/36/6/">Thing1</option>
<option value="/random-file/50/4/">Thing2</option>
```

I just need a way to extract both data and store it , **"/random-file/76/6/" & "Thing"**

Comment: If the answer is what you want you can mark it accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the values in a `dict`:

```
example = """<option value="/random-file/76/6/">Thing</option>
<option value="/random-file/36/6/">Thing1</option>
<option value="/random-file/50/4/">Thing2</option>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(example, "html.parser")

options = {}

for o in soup.find_all("option"):
    options[o["value"]] = o.text

print (options)
```

Outputs:

> > {u'/random-file/36/6/': u'Thing1', u'/random-file/76/6/': u'Thing', u'/random-file/50/4/': u'Thing2'}

Comment: Could Someone explain to me how this line works , I understand the basic concept tuples & dict ,  but could you refer me to a website to learn about this or explain it , thank you very much !

Comment: You are creating a new dict item. The key will be the `value`  attribute of the current node and the corresponding value will be the text of the current node. Please read the following doc: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Comment: I'm thankful , could you elaborate on this line ..............
options[o["value"]] = o.text